# Renaming a variable number of dataframes from a single object in R

Tags: r, readxl

I am trying to understand how to write a loop in R to rename a variable number of data frames.
If I run this code:

```
library("readxl")
path <- readxl_example("datasets.xls")
MyObject<-lapply(excel_sheets(path), read_excel, path = path)
```

I get an object that contains 4 tibbles.  If I want to rename them as File1 - File4,  I can use

```
File1<-MyObject[[1]]
```

And so on for each one separately. However, I am dealing with files that have varying numbers of worksheets, and so end up with variable numbers of dataframes in my object. 
So my question is; how do I tell R to rename each tibble as File1, File2, etc for as many tibbles are in the object?  I would welcome a specific answer, but if there is a tutorial out there that talks about writing loops (for beginners) that people recommend, I would welcome that as well.

Comment: Is it just about the renaming? or what is your goal with the single tibbles?

Comment: Do you mean variable numbers of worksheets?

Comment: @Val To expand: I have data that comes off the instrument as a separate spreadsheet for each day, with the exact same variables, in each sheet.  I want to combine the spreadsheets into a single data frame so that I can plot it all together.  The command I know for this is rbind, but 'rbind(MyObject[[1]])' returns an error of "MyObject not found".  So my solution was to extract each tibble as a separate data set, which then works with rbind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?
A basic `R` loop is just something like `for (i in start:end) {}`

```
for (i in 1:length(MyObject)) {
    assign(paste0("File", i), MyObject[[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Knowing what you just commented, I can suggest a solution which is IMHO superior to a loop:

Since you used `lapply` to load your excel sheets, I assume that `MyObject` is a list of single `data.frames`.

So to combine them to a single `data.frame`, just run `alldfs <-
 do.call(rbind,MyObject)`.

That should give you one single `data.frame` without any looping or single variables.